# How to show ${USER_FRIENDLY_NAME} as title and ${MESSAGE} as body of Push notification payload in Programmable Chat of Twilio?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to show title as ${USER_FRIENDLY_NAME} and body as ${MESSAGE} in Push noification of Programmable chat in twilio

I tried to configure in **Push Notification Configuration** module of Programmable chat of twilio console.

**Right now show:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

If somebody could help, it would be really appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch every detail of your push notification by setting up `NotificationServiceExtension` and `NotificationContent` in your Xcode project. If you don't have an idea about these stuff, these are used in rich push notification.

In your `UNNotificationServiceExtension`, you could catch your data there and decide what to show to the user.

```
func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
```

Helpful links:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/creating-ios-rich-push-notifications

Comment: I need to configure through twilio service not programatically in ios

Comment: Then I suppose your question is not a programming question for SO. You should file a ticket or contact their CS if you can't find a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can setup a template for your push notifications so they appear with the text that you want.

Check out the documentation for [Twilio Chat Push Notification templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/push-notification-configuration#push-templates) for more information.

I'm not sure there are specific title and subtitles available within iOS push notifications, but if you need to include a line break. Have you tried including `"\n"` within your template?